# How to assign keys to items in an object array?

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to turn

```
{"john":15, "alex":19, "mark":19, "luke":12}
```

into

```
const data = [
  { name: "john", value: 15},
  { name: "alex", value: 19},
  { name: "mark", value: 19},
  { name: "luke", value: 12},
];
```

Thanks any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4):

can solve using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the  [object entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
const a = {"john":15, "alex":19, "mark":19, "luke":12}

const res = Object.entries(a).map(([name,value]) => ({name,value}))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) & [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) :

```js
const obj = { john: 15, alex: 19, mark: 19, luke: 12 };
const array = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const [ name, value ] = [curr[0],curr[1]];
  return acc.concat({ name, value });
}, []);
console.log(array);
```